# Moodle Installation Error: This site can't be reached during installation

Tags: apache, xampp, moodle

I am running moodle on windows using xampp and I completed the first two steps, when I press next it gives me the "This site can't be reached" Page.

[image: Path Confirmation Window]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the solution to this issue.

Goto xampp control panel and open Apache->Config->httpd.conf.

[image]
Then add the below code to the end.

```js
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

Source: [Click Here](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=387587)